# EditText in RelativeLayout issue in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I currently have a layout defined as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/valueEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="EditText"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="right"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/valueEditText"
        android:text="Label"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:maxLines="1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout is used for rendering of a few ListView items.
This layout is rendered correctly at first. The EditText is aligned to the right and expands to the left when typing:

[image: Screenshot 1]

However, when typing in the EditText, the expanding text field will eventually overlap the Label textview:

[image]

Is there any way to make the EditText wrap and go multiline so that the Label textview doesn't get overlapped? 
I know I could use android:maxWidth="XXdp" attribute on the EditText but considering that the contents of the Label textview (and therefore it's size) may change dynamically I don't think that's the best way to do it.

Comment: you can fix no. or characters :-
 android:maxLength="20"

Comment: You can use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout and fix the weight for your EditText and TextView.

Answer (score 2):

2 changes required..

1- Make the width of the editText static like `android:layout_width="150dip"`

2- add this line `android:singleLine="true"` which wont allow the `edittext` go second line.

so basically...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/valueEditText"
    android:layout_width="150dip" //this line
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:text="EditText"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:singleLine="true" //and this line
    android:gravity="right"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/valueEditText"
    android:text="Label"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:maxLines="1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: How about setting a `android:maxWidth` instead of fixed dimension?

Comment: @gunar good technique too, but the `edittext` will start small then get bigger until it reach the value of `maxWidth` which it doesnt provide a good look

Comment: Using singleLine is probably not the best idea because of the fact that I want the edittext to be multi line. (As stated in my question)
That said, While settings the width or maxwidth does solve my problem initially, it might lead to problems regarding the fact that the content of the Label field changes dynamically (and thereby can decrease and increase in size)

Comment: oh sorry I thought i didnt want the multiline feature. but I didnt understand, how making fixed width would affect the textView, are you going to assign the text in edittext to the label?

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be wrapping the EditText and the TextView in a LinearLayout, which should prevent overlapping.

Comment: Somehow, even in a linearlayout with the weight of the views set overlapping still occurs. When I remove the android:maxLines="1" from the textview there's no overlapping but the TextView starts wrapping instead when there's no space left. This is kind of the behaviour I'm looking for, but instead of the textview I want the edittext to start multi-line wrapping when there's no space left. But whatever I try in a LinearLayout, it's always the TextView that wraps.

Comment: Hmm.. Set the layout_weight property of the TextBox to be higher than the TextView. Also try to set them both to fill_parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use following edit.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Label"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/valueEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/labelTextView"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="EditText "
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```